# What to do when you need AWS lambda function to run more than 15 minutes, aka the max timeout?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I wrote a lambda function in Python3.x to compress the videos uploaded to a S3 bucket and after that to convert the videos to different qualities.

However, when I was testing the lambda function, I noticed the max timeout I could set was 15 minutes. Whereas, it took 6 minutes to compress a test video I uploaded to AWS S3 and another 9 minutes to convert the video to a lower quality (and because time was out, the first conversion didn't finish).

I searched and read some articles. Some suggested AWS EC2, some AWS SQS and so forth. But I didn't really find a solution to deal with my issue.

Could you tell me are there any other approaches that could potentially be in place of the existing lambda function or working together with it to achieve the same purpose? Or if you have any good resources regarding AWS EC2 dealing with large files, could you share those?

If you could write some examples with video compression, it's more than welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

AWS Batch is the perfect alternative for your use case. It can queue up your jobs and run them on available compute resources(EC2). You can also specify EC2 spot instances as your compute resource for cost effective usage. You Lambda function will have to be translated into a Docker image as AWS Batch accepts only Docker images.

You can refer this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should consider using [Elastic Transcoder](https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/) or [AWS Elemental MediaConvert](https://aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/) in your case.

As an answer to your question, it is always better to create smaller Lambda functions and coordinate them using [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) to create a workflow.